# Using fsolve command in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, equation-solving

How can I solve these kind of equations?

```
(-1.5/w)*sin(w*t) + 1.5*t - 0.45 = 0
```

Knowing that:

```
w = sqrt(10)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this equation group of 2 equations this way:

```
solution = solve('w = sqrt(10)', '(-1.5/w)*sin(w*t) + 1.5*t - 0.45 = 0')
```

To check the solution:

```
solution.t
ans =
0.59963230021859138687907507892006

solution.w
ans =
3.1622776601683793319988935444327
```

To confirm that the solution works:

```
(-1.5/solution.w)*sin(solution.w*solution.t) + 1.5*solution.t - 0.45
ans =
0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : nrz's solution is correct.

One way is to evaluate the function explicitly and plot a graph. Try the following code in Matlab.

`w = sqrt(10);` 
   `t=(-100:0.01:100);`
Let,
    `R=(-1.5/w)*sin(w*t) + 1.5*t - 0.45;`

Then,

```
plot(t,R,'k')
 axis square;
 grid on;
```

You will get Figure-1;

[image: Figure-1]

`Upon zooming closer near (0,0), you will see the following structure of the graph (Figure-2).

[image: Figure-2]

Above, I have provided a numerical solution to this problem. Although, there is another method available (symbolic algebra) in Matlab. But matlab is primarily made for numerical computing and numerical solving of problems. Matlab is very inappropriate and slow for symbolic problem solving. Although the present question is a very small problem and won't be any trouble doing in Matlab using symbolic calculations as well, but still it is a good practice to do a problem numerically in matlab and symbolically in mathematica/maple etc.

Comment: But in the case that you need to solve symbolic equations inside larger MATLAB program (solving the equation is only a intermediate step), it's probably more convenient to solve them using MATLAB instead of calling Mathematica/Maple/etc.

Comment: @nrz Ive updated it. please read the first line of my reply. 
:)